# Can I make objects in a 3D Window clickable in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

I'm modeling some boxes with simple rectangles and I use the "on click" property to show information about its contents. However this only works for the 2D view, and I do need to have a 3D view where this functionality is also available because the boxes can be on top of each other.

I noticed that actual 3D objects do not have an "on click" property at all. Is it possible to make objects clickable in a 3D Window?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only way you can click 3D objects is by adding some 2D element that is clickable on top of it, perhaps with transparent color, which will allow you to click the 3D object in a 2D animation.

Nevertheless in a 3D window, it's definitely not possible to interact with any object through mouse clicking

Nevertheless if you want to display information by clicking an object in 3D you can instead have a text object to display that information in 3D and you can make that object visible or not when you need.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I have too many agents and way too much information to display to be able to use your suggestion. I have an idea for a workaround, but I just wanted to be sure that what I would like to do is not possible indeed.